# convert UTC time to PST in yii2?

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone, yii2

I am saving date/time in UTC timezone in my database.
like : **2015-07-22 17:08:11**

I want to convert this time to pacific time zone  **2015-07-22 11:07:18**.

Yet know I am using this function :

```
public static function UTCToPST($format, $time) {
    $dst = intval(date("I", $time));
    $tzOffset = intval(date('Z', time()));
    return date($format, $time + $tzOffset - 28800 + $dst * 3600);
  }
```

What should I have to do to get time in **2015-07-22 11:07:18** format?
or there is any other good way in yii2 for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your method of calculating the offset is flawed.  The *current* offset is not necessarily the correct offset to use for the time provided, due to daylight saving time and other time zone oddities.  You should be using PHP's `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I always store date/time as Unix Time Stamp in database (use INT(11)  in MySQL)

Because it is Unix Time Stamp, simply use PHP date() to convert it to datetime to your predefined timezone